# try to run soql query

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql, sfdx

runing this query

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT MemberName, MemberType, ChangedBy, RevisionCounter FROM SourceMember" -t -u vscodeOrg
```

i got this error

sObject type 'SourceMember' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

i want help

i ty to get all chage made in organisation

Comment: do you have a table in salesforce called "SourceMember" ? did you try the query here? https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what environment you are running this query in (like a sandbox or a developer edition or a scratch org), but the possible change that is required before accessing **SourceMember** object that you might be missing is to enable **Enable Source Tracking in the production Dev Hub org.**.

> ### Special Access Rules
>
> To access SourceMember, turn on **Enable Source Tracking in Developer and Developer Pro Sandboxes in the production Dev Hub org**. Once turned on, SourceMember appears in sandbox orgs after refresh. Scratch orgs automatically have the SourceMember object.

So, enable this and most probably you will be able to run the above mentioned query.

For more details you may refer to following Salesforce Developer Page:
[SourceMember(Tooling API Objects)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.244.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sourcemember.htm)